# Download Multiple video files simultaneously in ios sdk

Tags: ios, ipad

i have to download multiple files from the server simultaneously.Currently i am downloading a single video at a time and its working completely fine. Below is the code for the same. Now i need to download multiple videos simultaneously and maintain separate progress bar for all downloads in progress. And will this code work of big videos download or there is better approach for it.

Thanks

//Global header variables

```
float contentSize;
NSMutableData *responseAsyncData;
UIProgressView *progressBar;
```

//Code for creating connection

```
NSString *requestString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:VIDEO_LINK];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString] cachePolicy:NO timeoutInterval:15.0];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

And handling the callbacks like this ..

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        contentSize = [httpResponse expectedContentLength];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    if(responseAsyncData==nil)
    {
        responseAsyncData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    }
    [responseAsyncData appendData:data];
    float progress = (float)[responseAsyncData length] / (float)contentSize;
    [progressBar setProgress:progress];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError* error;

    if(responseAsyncData)
    {
       //filepath = Path to my location where i am storing
        BOOL pass = [responseAsyncData writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
        if (pass) {
            NSLog(@"Saved to file: %@", filepath);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Video not saved.");
        }
        [progressBar setProgress:0];
    }
    responseAsyncData = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate your downloading code into a subclass of `NSOperation`.  Then you can use an `NSOperationQueue` to run the downloads asynchronously, allow a certain number to be done in parallel, etc.

I haven't read this tutorial, but it looks very thorough: http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues